# There exists no x, y and z satisfying the conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question**: Prove that there exist no positive integers $x, y $ & $z$ satsifying

- $$2xz=y^2$$
- $$ x+z=997 $$

**My attempt:**
$$ 2 | y^2 \qquad \Rightarrow 4|y^2 \qquad \Rightarrow 2|xz $$
Please suggest ways to proceed.

Comment: That is hardly an attempt. But divisibility by 2 is the key.

Comment: I'm stuck after that step @henrik

Comment: There is no c is my name! It's not a good place to start, start with the other equation.

Comment: Do I assume one of them to be a multiple of 2?

Comment: you don't have to it's implied ...

Comment: @Viraam Assume? Why? Since $2\mid xy$, one of them *must* be even.

Comment: Oops! Sorry for that @Henrik

Comment: Ohh yes.. thats true. It's implied

Comment: what else does 4 dividing into $y^2$ imply ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Im not very sure... Any other clue?

Comment: you you double the sides of a square what happens to the area ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee It increases four times

Comment: okay so what does $y^2$ dividing by 4 mean

Comment: The sides of the square is reduced to half... @RoddyMacPhee

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality $x$ is even and $z$ odd, and $2$ divides $y^2$ an even number of times so $x=2^k r$ with $k,\,r,\,z$ odd. Since $997$ is prime $r,\,z$ are coprime, but since $rz$ is a perfect square $r,\,z$ are squares. Thus $997$ is of the form $2a^2+\sqrt{r}^2$ with $3|a$ by inspection, i.e. $997=18b^2+\sqrt{r}^2$ (say) with $b^2\le 55$. There are few enough cases left you can check them by hand.

Comment: 996 isn't prime.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thanks; I've fixed that typo.